# curl errors: could not resolve host, java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Sorry for posting this as this might be a simple problems to experts but to me as a beginner it is an important issue to resolve. I have created a `WSO2 DSS service` where it has a `MYSQL` table datasource named `users(userid(auto_increment),first_name,last_name,password).`

I created specific queries for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and also resources to accommodate these request. When I started testing the service using cURL GET and DELETE, it was working and I was able to retrieve and delete data. However when I was trying to insert (POST) and update (PUT) data I'm getting multiple errors
shown below:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: first_name curl: (6) Could not
 resolve host: last_name curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password
 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
 authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type Vary:
 Accept-Encoding Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 Date: Fri, 08
 Aug 2014 05:05:43 GMT Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP Transfer-Encoding:
 chunked
```

---

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 - Error
 report</title><style><!--H1
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
 H2
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
 H3
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
 BODY
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
 B
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
 {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color :
 #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - String index out of range: 1</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b>
 Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>String index out of range:
 -1</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented t from fulfilling this
 request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b>
 <pre>java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
 range: -1
         java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
         rg.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.extractParametersFromRequest(XFormURLEncodedBilder.java:174)
         rg.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.processDocument(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:12)
         rg.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:188)
         org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:146)
         org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processXMLRequest(RESTUtil.java:65)
         org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processXMLRequest(AxisServlet.java:826)
         org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPut(AxisServlet.java:317)
         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:758)
         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
         org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
         org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
         org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
         org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
         org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
```

Here are the cURL commands that I used:

```
POST - curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer f56ce778dee04274eba0eab3e9d7b324" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d {"first_name":"chris","last_name":"paul","password":"cp3"} http://ip:port/SampleDSS/user/

PUT - curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer f56ce778dee04274eba0eab3e9d7b324" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d {"userid":11,"first_name":"chris","last_name":"paul","password":"cp3"} http://ip:port/SampleDSS/user/
```

Can you please point out if there is any prob with the `cURL` command or the `JSON` format data that I'm using?

Any substantial help would be welcomed.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your JSON data as follows:

```
curl -i \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer f56ce778dee04274eba0eab3e9d7b324" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PUT \
    -d '{"_postuser":{"userid":11,"first_name":"chris","last_name":"paul","password":"cp3"}}' \
    http://ip:port/SampleDSS/user/
```

It seems that your request is being processed as an XML request. You probably want to add a `Content-Type` header to indicate that you're sending JSON content.

Comment: Hi Robby, Thanks for the format but when I tried testing it, it is still giving me a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1. Is there a problem with the data format that is being posted?

Comment: @Drew Looking into that now. Are the `curl` errors gone, at least?

Comment: Yes Robby, they are gone.

Comment: @Drew I've updated my answer a couple of times, but it seems there are a number of issues.

Comment: Yes that's right the data type should be JSON, sorry forgot to mention it. I've tried using the format you gave, this time it's a different error javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unexpected end of json stream. Seems there is a problem with the input data on JSON format. Sorry about this I'm new to JSON and WSO2 products but this is what my superiors are requiring me to do.

Comment: Maybe try without the `data=` this time? Do you have a stacktrace? The JSON data in itself looks absolutely fine.

Comment: i did try without "data=" and got a more specific error "Input JSON message is not valid expected : _postuser but found : first_name" it seems I have to declare what object it is related to the table which is users. Do you have any idea on how to put it inside the input data?

Comment: You could try `{"_postuser":{ "first_name":"chris", ... }}`

Comment: Great news indeed! I've updated my answer to add the `_postuser` part.